# What are more advanced techniques than ARIMA?

Tags: time-series, prediction, forecasting, arima

For timeseries predication cases, what other techniques are available in statistics or machine/deep learning other than MA (moving average), ARMA, and ARIMA?

Comment: Can you be more specific what type of timeseries prediction task you're interested in?

Answer (score 1):

More advanced methods do exist for time series analysis, such as LTSM. For a further discussion of this and other advanced time series models, here are two links to papers further discussing them.

https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10186768
[https://stanford.edu/~koenecke/files/Deep_Learning_for_Time_Series_Tutorial.pdf](https://stanford.edu/%7Ekoenecke/files/Deep_Learning_for_Time_Series_Tutorial.pdf)